# Why is a new docker image the same size of the original one from which the commit was made?

Tags: docker, storage

I downloaded a Docker image and made some changes inside a container based on it. Then I commited those changes to create a new image that I would actually like to use.

`docker images` says that these images have about the same size. So, it seemed to me that Docker copied everything it needs to the new image.

Yet I can't remove the old image which I no longer need. It seems like I'm getting the worst of both worlds: neither is space conserved by a parenting relationship, nor can I delete the unwanted files.

What gives? Am I interpreting `docker images` output wrong (maybe it's not reporting the actual on-disk size)?

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you made those changes?

Comment: The size you see is not the actual size on disk. Images are layered and layers are reused.

As a side note, you should not make changes inside containers. Try to replicate those changes in a Dockerfile and then build the image from that.

Comment: You should pretty much never use `docker commit` in the way you describe.  Say a year goes by, you discover there's a major security issue in the original image, and you need to rebuild your custom image.  You can `docker pull` an updated image, but will you remember exactly what "made some changes inside a container" means?  Better to write a Dockerfile you can commit to source control and re-run as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may remove the first image with a force,

```bash
docker image rm -f $IMAGE_ID
```

As for the same size, it depends mainly on your changes, you can check if they match exactly on a byte level with:

```bash
docker image inspect IMAGE_NAME:$TAG --format='{{.Size}}'
```